# If and ActiveSelf. Only works once. With example project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

First time developer here and I am struggling with a problem.
I made a mock up of the problem in regular Unity 3d since the VR scares some talented people away from helping me. That can be downloaded here: https://gofile.io/d/qHDlUZ
File is a zip called: SoundTestTroubleShooting. A Unity build on 24.7MB
Follow the number on the buttons.
Button 1 "Choose Music" Activates the Cube.
Button 2/4 "Play Music" Checks if cube is activated and plays song if that is the case.
Button 3 "Restart Scene" Stops the music and reloads the scene.
Cube has dontdestroyonload.
After that i press button 2/4"PlayMusic" and it cant find that the cube is active.
WHY?! Going nuts here.

Old text with the entire problem here:

In my game I have four songs in the start menu that my player gets to choose from. He chooses one by pressing one of four buttons. This activates an empty GameObject, lets call it SmileMusicTrigger. SmileMusicTrigger has a dontdestroyonload and is deactivated by the other three buttons if player wants to switch song.

Player press Begin which moves him into position. He presses start and this button has:

```
 public GameObject SmileMusicTrigger;
public GameObject EpicMusicTrigger;
public GameObject GodMusicTrigger;
public GameObject VikingMusicTrigger;

void OnTriggerEnter()
   {
    if (SmileMusicTrigger.activeSelf)
    {
        AudioManager.instance.Play("Smile");
    }
    if (EpicMusicTrigger.activeSelf)
    {
        AudioManager.instance.Play("Epic");
    }
    if (GodMusicTrigger.activeSelf)
    {
        AudioManager.instance.Play("God");
    }
    if (VikingMusicTrigger.activeSelf)
    {
        AudioManager.instance.Play("Viking");
```

and my game start and and the music begins fine.
When player dies he restarts the scene with restart button which has this to say about the music:

```
   void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    AudioManager.instance.Stop("Smile");
    AudioManager.instance.Stop("Viking");
    AudioManager.instance.Stop("God");
    AudioManager.instance.Stop("Epic");
```

}
}

after this code has run the scene restarts and it does not seem like my Start button can check the active state of SmileMusicTrigger again. I know SmileMusicTrigger is active through the restart of the scene because I see it under dontdestroy in the hierarchy when game is running and it is checked as on in inspector. But I cant seem to call it again. Thus my music only plays once.

Audiomanager is also under Donotdestroy so I dont think the problem is there.

Sorry if this is messy. I am working really hard to get this working but I am so stuck right now.
Thankful for any help.
All the best!

Comment: any errors in the console the second time you play?

Comment: No errors that has with this to do. It warns that there are no audiolisteners once during the scene restart. But I do have sound from permanent objects so that does not seem to be it either.

Comment: Are the "Begin" button and the "Start" button you refer to different buttons?

Comment: Yes. I have a perch in a tree that is the menu. When player press begin I move the player to the play area. There he can press "Start, or "Ready player one" as I call it. This is only a transport and a deactivation of the perch menu. It should not, and does indeed not seem to,  interfere with the SmileMusicTrigger or anything else in audio.

Comment: I'm just wondering, because you're using OnTriggerEnter(), is the trigger only called once, because it's only called when your player presses "Begin".  This moves them into the trigger, which fires the OnTriggerEnter method.  When they die, do they restart on the perch again, or do they restart already inside the trigger/play area?

Comment: Player starts in play area. There he can choose to immedietly press "Ready player one" or go to "Menu". Every time Player has pressed "Ready player one" and succeded or failed, the game scene reloads. thats when I loose control over my music. But I can go up to menu and activate it again. even though it is already activated according to inspector during play. this is very strange